# How to make own gallery in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have been making a mobile game for android in unity using C# where the user can make a picture and then save their picture once they are done. The image is saved to their device as a PNG. I would like to have the user be able to view all the images that are saved in the folder in a gallery type screen with a next and back button in order to see all the images they have made.

I am able to load a single image using the following code but it doesn't show up until i go back a screen and go into the galley screen again. i have tried looping it through but i can't get it to work.

```
public class GalleryScreen : MonoBehaviour {
string[] filePaths;
int x = 0;
WWW www;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("load_image");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
IEnumerator load_image()
{

        filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath + "CountryHorse/pics/", "*.png");

        www = new WWW("file://" + filePaths[x]);
        yield return www;
        Texture2D temp = new Texture2D(0, 0);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(temp);


        GetComponent<Image>().material.mainTexture = temp;

}

public void next()
{
    x++;
    if (x > filePaths.Length) x = 0;


}

public void back()
{

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) When working with UnityEngine.UI.Image component, you don't change the image like you do: `GetComponent<Image>().material.mainTexture = temp;`

Image uses sprites. Instead of changing the material texture, you should set its sprite property. You can create sprite from texture using Sprite.Create:

```
GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(temp, new Rect(0, 0, temp.width, temp.height), Vector2.zero);
```

2) In `next()` function, did you mean to also put `StartCoroutine("load_image")`? Else how are you planning to switch the images?

3) Keep in mind, that textures / sprites are not garbage collected, so you should make sure to destroy the unused ones using `Destroy` function.

4) Not a big deal, but you have a typo - it should be `if (x >= filePaths.Length) x = 0;`, not `if (x > filePaths.Length) x = 0;`. When `x == filePaths.Length` it is overflow already.

**EDIT**

Here is your code slightly modified with all the above points:

```
public class GalleryScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    string[] filePaths;
    int x = 0;
    WWW www;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("load_image");
    }

    IEnumerator load_image()
    {

        filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath + "CountryHorse/pics/", "*.png");

        www = new WWW("file://" + filePaths[x]);
        yield return www;
        Texture2D temp = new Texture2D(0, 0);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(temp);

        var img = GetComponent<Image>();
        if (img != null) {
            if (img.sprite != null) {
                // Clean up the old textures
                Destroy(img.sprite.texture);
                Destroy(img.sprite);
            }
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(temp, new Rect(0, 0, temp.width, temp.height), Vector2.zero);
        }

    }

    public void next()
    {
        x++;
        if (x >= filePaths.Length) x = 0;
        StartCoroutine("load_image");

    }

    public void back()
    {
        x--;
        if (x < 0) x = filePaths.Length - 1;
        StartCoroutine("load_image");
    }
}
```

Additionally, pay attention that on mobile platforms `Application.dataPath` behaves differently - it is more or less useless for you, in Android simply pointing to apk, in iOS to read only Data folder. For your work pattern, where user can save his own pictures, you should use `Application.persistentDataPath`, there you can read and write. If you want to be able to read/write also outside persistentDataPath, to sdcard for example, your app will need additional permissions. See for more info:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

Comment: 1. yes thank you that part worked. Everywhere else i looked it said to use a texture that is why I did that way. 2. i have tried having the Coroutine in the next function and it doesn't work there. the x increases but the picture doesn't change. 3. how do i use the destroy function? 4. yes a silly mistake on my part thank you

Comment: I just added sample code to the answer which illustrates the required modifications, please have a look.

Comment: Thank you man you have been a big help. But the next and back buttons still don't work. They still just stay on the same image even when there are others in the folder

Comment: This is weird because I tested it and it worked fine, and actually there is no reason it won't work, it a very simple script. It is unlikely the problem is in the code. Few things you may want to check: are the other pictures in the folder also PNG? (if there are JPGs for example they won't be visible). Maybe add a debug print of filePaths array to see which files are actually visible in the folder. Also, does it happen only on device, or also in Editor mode? Or only Editor? Do your buttons actually call next / back (I know it may sound obvious, but sometimes we miss those obvious things)?

Comment: i ran the debug and it shows each file there. I also ran a debug and it loads each image into the www it just not changing the image. The next and back buttons work in the fact the x changes and it does show in the debug it is putting a different file in the www. When i ran it on my android device none of the images showed up at all. I am not getting any errors and it seems like it should work no problem not really understanding what i am missing.

Comment: OK, last try, if not - I am out of clues, sorry. First - about running it on Android, see edit to my answer. Second, I missed it previously, but you should put "/" before "CountryHorse/pics/", Application.dataPath does not end with "/". Now, we know the first picture loads. You can see load_image running, but there is no effect. If there is an error while loading picture via WWW, picture should change into small "?" shaped bitmap, so it is not this either. So it means image changes successfully, but, maybe it is a wrong image? Any chance you have several instances of this script in your scene?

Comment: i changed Application.PersistentDataPath for both for the save and loading aspects. now i get this error      You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
' Couldn't open file /Users/Skip/AppData/LocalLow/Rew Studios/Country Horse Design/pics/Horse_13-15-57.png
UnityEngine.WWW:LoadImageIntoTexture(Texture2D)
<load_image>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/GalleryScreen.cs:32)   '      it saves on the editor but on my tablet it doesn't save an image.